# How to get values from dynamically created(ajax) textboxes in jsp?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

here is my code

index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="javascript">

    var xmlHttp;
    var f=1;
    var t = "text";

    function showState()
    { 
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject){
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        if (xmlHttp==null){
                alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
            return
        } 
        var url="additem.jsp";
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;

        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    function stateChange(){   
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){  
            document.getElementById(t).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            t = "text"+f.toString();
            f=f+1;
        }  
    }

</script></head>

<body>
<center>
<form action=AddProd1.jsp method=post>
Enter Catagory  <td><BLOCKQUOTE></BLOCKQUOTE><BLOCKQUOTE><center><input type=text name=catagory></BLOCKQUOTE></td>
</center>
<br><br>

<div id='text'></div><br>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
<input type=submit value=new onclick="showState();">


</body></html>
```

additem.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="ob" class="te.tes" scope="session" />
<%! 

    String value = "";
    String t = "" ;
    String v="";
 %>

<%  
    v=ob.Increase();
    value = "product" + v;  
    t = "text" + v;
%>
<html>
<input type=text name=product value="<%=value%>">
<div id='<%=t%>'></div><br>
</html>
```

AddProd1.jsp:

```
<%  int i;
    String [] value = request.getParameterValues("product")
    for(i=0;i<value.length;i++)
        out.println(value[i]);

%>
```

I am getting exception in "value.length" in AddProd1.jsp no matter what i try....I even tried to get one value by only putting request.getParameter("product")...But i get null value in return ....what am i doing wrong??? Thanx in advace..

Comment: Try to learn & use `jQuery`.

Comment: thanx for the advice...but it still not my answer...